# how do I match negative regex?

Tags: regex, negate

There is a sharepoint url  :
`http://teamspace.abc.com/sites/ABC/?list=%7bCEE6E6CB-A035-4FF9-Af95-98784D732938%7d`

The `listID` could be various but I only want to allow the above one. Therefore, it shouldn't match:

`http://teamspace.abc.com/sites/ABC/?list=%7bDEXXXXxxxx-A035-4FF9-Af95-98784D732938%7d url`

Is there any way I can match only if url is the following: `http://teamspace.abc.com/sites/ABC/?list=%7bCEE6E6CB-A035-4FF9-Af95-98784D732938%7d"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

better use == operator (equals() in java and C#)

```
String http = "http";
String shp = "sharepoint";
String url = "://teamspace.abc.com/sites/ABC/?list=%7bCEE6E6CB-A035-4FF9-Af95-98784D732938%7d";
if(myUrl.equals(http+url) || myUrl.equals(shp+url))
{
    //do what you want
}
example for java
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var url = "(http|sharepoint)://teamspace.abc.com/sites/ABC/?list=%7bCEE6E6CB-A035-4FF9-Af95-98784D732938%7d"

if (listID == url)
```